# How to configure to use aspectj in scala play application

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, aop

I have:

- SBT version 1.3.8
- Play Framework 7.1
- Scala 2.12.3

I want to use AOP in Play. What I tried is:

```scala
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

@Aspect
class AnnotationBasedAspect {
  /**
   * around execution of Sum
   */
  @Around("execution(@aop1.Loggable * *.*(..))")
  def aroundSum(joinPoint: ProceedingJoinPoint): Object = {
    val result = joinPoint.proceed
    println("Method:-" + joinPoint.toShortString() + " Input:-" + joinPoint.getArgs().toList.mkString(",") + " Result:-" + result)
    result
  }
}
```

```scala
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface Loggable {}
```

```scala
class Sum {
   @Loggable
   def checkSum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
}
```

```scala
object AopMain {
  def main(args:Array[String]){
    val sum = new Sum().checkSum(1, 2)
    println("sum is---"+sum)
  }
}
```

I am getting the sum but Aspects are not applying.

Am i missing anything?

Added this to *plugins.sbt*:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.nstojiljkovic" % "sbt-aspectj-runner-play-2.7" % "1.2.3")
```

And used this in *build.sbt*:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.codehaus.mojo" % "aspectj-maven-plugin" % "1.11"
```